# Max value of a field with mongo-java-driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to get max value of `date` field for whole collection `4programmers`.

In mongo shell I can write:

```
db.getCollection("4programmers").aggregate([
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: null,
            max : {$max:  "$date"}
        }
    }
])
```

and it returns a document with the date `ISODate("2017-10-20T17:12:37.000+02:00")` but when I write in java:

```
Date d = collection.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Aggregates.group("$date", Accumulators.max("maxx", "$date"))
                        )
                ).first().getDate("maxx");
        System.out.println(d);
```

as a result I get: `Fri Oct 20 00:44:50 CEST 2017`

May something is wrong with `first()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First argument of `Aggregates.group` should be null instead of "$date" (it's actually  `_id: null`).
So code should look like:

```
Date d = collection.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Aggregates.group(null, Accumulators.max("maxx", "$date"))
                        )
                ).first().getDate("maxx");
```

or you can do the same without Aggregates class:

```
collection.aggregate(asList(new Document("$group", new Document("_id", null)
                .append("max", new Document("$max", "$date")))))
                .first().getDate("max");
```